# How to connect to wireless network through cmd in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I'm working on a script that will automatically connect users to our organization's wireless network, and I need a way to automatically prompt users for their credentials on the first connection to the network.

For example, in Win7 I can get a balloon notification to pop up, and once a user clicks on that notification a window pops up asking for a user's credentials.

My issue is that I can't seem to get a balloon notification to pop up on Win8, and even when I run
`netsh wlan connect ssid=################`
nothing happens. Command prompt tells me the command executed successfully, but I don't get any prompts.

However, if I manually enter credentials (go to the sidebar, click connect, etc.) and then run the `netsh` command, it will connect. Is there a way for me to prompt for user credentials without having the user go through the process of clicking the sidebar, then clicking connect, then entering their credentials?